# Communicate with clients from windows service

Tags: .net, windows-services

Sorry in advance if question is not very clear.

**Background:** I have developed a .NET assembly that is consumed by COM objects hosted as windows service. I've done all required COM-related stuff. My assembly is registered, loaded by COM and successfully communicates with COM objects. In fact, my assembly is a proxy between COM and managed worlds. I mentioned COM only just to describe the situation.

**Goal:** my goal is to expose public CLR interface to allow other developers to utilize my proxy via this public interface.

**Question:** How it is usually accomplished? I could think of this solution: consumers register themselves somewhere and I shall read and use this registration information (assembly, class name that implements my public interface) to communicate with clients via that public interface.

**Special notes:** system service that loads and hosts my assembly runs under local system account. Loading arbitrary (and possibly malicious) client assembly into system context is considered a vulnerability. Any vulnerability in my code will compromise entire system.

What other options I should explore?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you use sockets? One solution could be implemented by creating a protocol that your application uses and listen on a port for incoming commands over the wire.

Comment: I don't use anything at the moment. And I'm not sure if opening port from local system context is a good idea. I thought, I can have a separate windows service that runs under limited account (network or local service, for example) and expose public contract via separate interface. But communication between both services is yet unclear for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Original project was declined and only recently it was brought up again. I've revisited the problem and ended up with two solutions:

1. use [Managed Extensibility Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/mef/) to load 3rd party pluggable modules into local system context (via interface). This can be used when plugin required local system access permissions.
2. use WCF for inter-process communication (say, using named pipes transport for local clients) when 3rd party module do not require local system access permissions and can run under different security context.